# How to use parameters in Linq FromSQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a list from Locations table and exclude the Locations already assigned to a user.  I am trying to using Linq FromSQL.  If I hard code the user.Id parameter the query works, when I use the user.Id variable it does not work.  Query returns all records.  When I run the debugger, the user.Id variable is correct.  Here is my code...

```
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Id);

var unassignedLocations = await _context.Location
       .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT LocationId FROM UserLocations WHERE UserID='{user.Id}')")
       .OrderBy(l => l.Name)
       .ToListAsync();

Locations = new SelectList(unassignedLocations, "Id", "Name");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are the enclosing quotes around the value

```
UserID='{user.Id}'
```

When using `FromSql` method overload with interpolated SQL string, rather than embedding the value inside the SQL string (which would allow SQL injection attacks), EF Core will bind a parameter for every placeholder inside the string - in this case, single parameter with value `= user.Id`.

Hence you have to access the value directly w/o enclosing it with quotes like constant:

```
WHERE UserID={user.Id}
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you Ivan.